# Impala add column to existing VIEW

Tags: cloudera, impala

I went through the [Cloudera docs](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/impala_alter_view.html).

It doesn't mention how to add a column to an existing view. Is it because there is no way to achieve that?
If I use `DESCRIBE FORMATTED` and use the original view definition of `select * from xyz`([an example is shown here](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-14-x/topics/impala_alter_view.html)) to drop the existing view and recreate the view with the same `userId`, will it work exactly as it did before?

Comment: You have to recreate the view. A view is only metadata, it doesn't affect to the data. When you change metadata remember to do `invalidate metadata`. It should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right - `DROP-CREATE` should work. Even `ALTER VIEW view_name AS SELECT  ..., new_col FROM table` should work. May be you can share what query you are trying and what is the error you are facing.